# How to avoid double clicking on a submit button in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

My c# web application has 2 panels. 1st panel is to enter some text.
The 2nd panel only shows after the 1st panel passes validation and the continue button is clicked.
The 2nd panel has a text box with 4 validations, a dropdown list box and a Submit button. 
If the validation is good and the user clicks on he Submit button, I would like the Submit button to be disabled and change it's text to "Please wait..." to prevent the user from double clicking it.
I'm new to .NET so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
protected void BTNSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Page.IsValid)
{
BTNSubmit.Text = "Please wait...";
BTNSubmit.Enabled = false;

DoSomething();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the above code? Is it failing? If so, what's the error? What else have you tried? SO is not a place for other people to do you work for you, it is a place for assistance.

Comment: Yes, I have tested the code and it does not achieve the result I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you will need to trap on the front end with javascript and asp.net's `onclientclick` attribute (which translates to javascript's `onclick`.)

An important key is that if your `onclientclick` returns false, your server event won't fire (which is what you want for the second click)

```
var submitted=false; //javascript variable to store if we have clicked submit yet

function ClientSubmit(obj){ //obj is your button
    if(submitted) {return false;} //return false prevents server onclick from firing
    submitted=true;
    obj.value='Please Wait...';
    obj.disabled = true;
    return true;  
}
```

Now the next time you click, your javascript will see that `submitted` is set to true, so this function will return false, and prevent the server event from firing

To implement this on your .aspx page

```
<asp:Button id="myButton" runat="server" 
 onclick="BTNSubmit_Click" onclientclick="return ClientSubmit(this);"  Text="Submit"/>
```

Comment: I switched `obj.innerHTML` to `obj.value` in the javascript function.  Can you be more specific?  When does the error occur?